# FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "assignedTo/dynamicID/ldap" at /Tasks for better performance

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client.Consider adding ".indexOn": "assignedTo/{dynamicText}/ldap" at /Tasks to your security rules for better performance.

I totally understand the warning. But I don't know how to implement this in firebase rule.

I'm using angularjs in this project.

**My DB:**

```
{
  "Tasks":{
       -LIC6mF9cXGVMyUfgLEE : {
          assignedTo:{ 
                dynamicText:{ 
                      ldap: ldapValue 
                 }, 
                dynamicText2:{ 
                      ldap: ldapValue 
                 } 
           },

           other properties...
        },
        -LIC6mF9cXGVMyUfgLEE : {
          assignedTo:{ 
                dynamicText3:{ 
                      ldap: ldapValue 
                 }, 
                dynamicText4:{ 
                      ldap: ldapValue 
                 } 
           },

           other properties...
        }
   }
 }
```

**My Code:**

```
getTaskListByUser: function (ldap, val) {
    var query = tasks.orderByChild("assignedTo/"+ldap+"/ldap").equalTo(val);
    return $firebaseArray(query);
  }
```

Thanks in advance.